# Will not boot beyond GRUB command line

Tags: boot, grub2

Upon installing rEDIt and Ubuntu on my Mac OS X Yosemite from a disk, Ubuntu Asked me to update. I say yes and it loads for a bit and flashes to a purple outline on a black box and sits there, I wonder what this is about and reboot. Now whenever I open my computer, it boots at the GRUB screen, when i want to boot Ubuntu I wait at a black screen with a flashing white underscore, and it stays there for hours not doing anything, it wont boot. HOW DO I FIX THIS??